# Migration of 32 bit OS Vc++ application to 64 bit OS Vc++ application

Tags: visual-c++, code-migration

i have an Vc++ application developed in VC6 . currently it supports 32 bit Operation systems.
My requirement to covert this application to support 64 bit Operating systems (like windows7 , Windoes 2008 server and etc..).

what are  easiest way / steps / procedure to migrate such of application?

Comment: Same as this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148170/supporting-64bit-os-which-currently-works-in-32-bit-os

Answer (score 1):

In practice, if you use every data type as it should, there shouldn't be a problem.
Typical errors that are made, are:

- using [unsigned] long instead of size_t when referring to sizes
- subtracting pointers and assigning the result to a long (should be ptrdiff_t or something like this)
- converting pointers to long or long to pointers

The page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384198%28v=VS.85%29.aspx on Microsoft's MSDN site gives a list of important things to think about when going to 64-bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For a 32 bit application to work on 64 bit OS do we need to compile our source using 64 bit compiler?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 has a command file that sets the necessary environment variables for your compilation.  Look for VCVARSALL.BAT.  Execute this in a command prompt and give it the wanted 'type of compilation'.  E.g. "VSVARSALL X86" sets everything ready for 32-bit compilations.  "VSVARSALL X64" sets everything ready for 64-bit compilations.